# Remove distributed tracing headers from Http requests .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, elastic-apm

I have ASP.NET project (.NET5) and sent requests to another API by HttpClient.
Also I add ElasticAPM to my project.
When I send a request Elastic add distributed tracing headers: traceparent, ...
I want to remove this headers, but only in one part of code where I create HttpClient, in another parts i want to save this headers.

I was trying to create custom DelegatingHandler, it's not working, also I try to remove DefaultRequestHeaders from client after creating, it's not working too.